# How to get the url in Swift3?

Tags: swift

I want to get the url in swift3, but it's not working.

[image]

```
var searchURL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Shawn+Mendes&type=track"
```

this is my script

[myscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp0po.png)

[when it's run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGbIH.png)

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to do ? Want you parse the response ? Doing a request ?

Comment: i want to get the data
print it out but the part for url is not working

Answer (score 2):

Your `searchURL` is just a `String` as it is now.

If you would like to use the `URL` class of Swift 3 you can create an instance by passing it a `String` containing the URL you would like address.

So in your case:

```
var searchURLString = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Shawn+Mendes&type=track"
if let searchURL = URL(string: searchURLString)  {
    print(searchURL.absoluteURL) // https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Shawn+Mendes&type=track
    print(searchURL.path) // /v1/search
    print(searchURL.lastPathComponent) // search
}
```

Notice that the `init` method of `URL` gives you an optional URL in return. This is to guard against invalid URL strings, meaning that if you try to create a URL from something like `URL(string: "this won't work")` you will get `nil` in return since that can not be mapped to a valid URL.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: thank
i try it but it's break at 
var searchURLString = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Shawn+Mendes&type=track"

Comment: sorry, what do you mean with break?

Comment: the part for varURL was Error
so it can not print anything out

Comment: OK, I'm not sure I completely understand. You say you get an error in this line `var searchURL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Shawn+Mendes&type=track"`? Do you see an error message?

Comment: i'm sorry about i can not express the problem clearly
when i build the script
that line change color and have a remind
Thread 1: breakpoint 1.5

Comment: i uploaded that picture in my quest

Comment: OK, and isn't that just because you have added a breakpoint there yourself? Can you continue the execution of your program (Ctrl + Cmd + y lets you continue the execution)